# How to watch for external custom resource changes in kubebuilder without importing the external type

Tags: go, kubernetes, kubebuilder

Suppose I have bellow code snippet which setups a reconciler that watches external resource "External":

```
// SetupWithManager sets up the controller with the Manager.
func (r *SomethingReconciler) SetupWithManager(mgr ctrl.Manager) error {
    return ctrl.NewControllerManagedBy(mgr).
        For(&api.Something{}).
        WithOptions(controller.Options{
            MaxConcurrentReconciles: stdruntime.NumCPU(),
            RecoverPanic:            true,
        }).
        Watches(
            &source.Kind{Type: &somev1.External{}},
            handler.EnqueueRequestsFromMapFunc(r.findInternalObjectsForExternal),
            builder.WithPredicates(predicate.Funcs{
                UpdateFunc: func(ue event.UpdateEvent) bool { return true },
                DeleteFunc: func(de event.DeleteEvent) bool { return true },
            }),
        ).
        Complete(r)
}
```

My problem is that I can not import `somev1.External` type into my project because importing the go module containing this type would break my current project's dependencies. 
Is there a way in kubebuilder to watch for external resources without having to explicitly importing their types? like GVK or something?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes it's possible.

You can create a REST client for your resource in `main.go` as below:

```golang
gvkExternal := schema.GroupVersionKind{
    Group:   "some.group.io",
    Version: "v1",
    Kind:    "External",
}

restClient, err := apiutil.RESTClientForGVK(gvkExternal, false, mgr.GetConfig(), serializer.NewCodecFactory(mgr.GetScheme()))
if err != nil {
    setupLog.Error(err, "unable to create REST client")
}
```

Then add a field for this REST client (`rest.Interface`) to your reconciler (`yournativeresource_controller.go`) struct such as:

```golang
type YourNativeResourceReconciler struct {
    client.Client
    Scheme        *runtime.Scheme
    // add this
    RESTClient    rest.Interface
}
```

Last, initialize your reconciler with this REST client (`main.go`):

```golang
if err = (&controllers.YourNativeResourceReconciler{
    Client:        mgr.GetClient(),
    Scheme:        mgr.GetScheme(),
    RESTClient:    restClient,
}).SetupWithManager(mgr); err != nil {
    setupLog.Error(err, "unable to create controller", "controller", "YourNativeResource")
    os.Exit(1)
}
```

Do not forget to add RBAC marker to your project (reconciler preferably) that will generate RBAC rules allowing you to manipulate `External` resource:

```
//+kubebuilder:rbac:groups=some.group.io,resources=externals,verbs=get;list;watch;create;update;patch;delete
```

After these steps, you can use REST client for manipulating `External` resource over `YourNativeResource` reconciler using `r.RESTClient`.

**EDIT:**

If you want to watch resources, dynamic clients may help. Create a dynamic client in `main.go`:

```golang
dynamicClient, err := dynamic.NewForConfig(mgr.GetConfig())
if err != nil {
    setupLog.Error(err, "unable to create dynamic client")
}
```

Apply above steps, add it to your reconciler etc. Then you will be able to watch `External` resource as below:

```golang
resourceInterface := r.DynamicClient.Resource(schema.GroupVersionResource{
    Group:    "some.group.io",
    Version:  "",
    Resource: "externals",
})
externalWatcher, err := resourceInterface.Watch(ctx, metav1.ListOptions{})
if err != nil {
    return err
}

defer externalWatcher.Stop()

select {
case event := <-externalWatcher.ResultChan():
    if event.Type == watch.Deleted {
        logger.Info("FINALIZER: An external resource is deleted.")
    }
}
```